# How to show label conditionally on the value of an attribute?

Tags: labeling, mapserver

In the MapServer Mapfile, I have this:

```
LABEL
    TEXT "Q=[Q] m³/h"
END
```

The problem is that for those features having an empty (null) `Q`, the result is `Q= m³/h`. Instead, I'd like it to not show anything. How can I achieve that?

Can I also conditionally exclude parts of the string? E.g.

```
LABEL
    TEXT "Q=[Q] m³/h D=[Diameter] mm"
END
```

Here the `Q=[Q] m³/h` part should show only if `Q` is not null, and the rest only if `Diameter` is not null.

Comment: Datasource from your layer using the label? Database, files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following because as mentioned at https://mapserver.org/mapfile/class.html#mapfile-class-label

> A class can contain multiple labels (since MapServer 6.2).

and https://mapserver.org/mapfile/label.html#label#mapfile-label-expression

> Expression that determines when the LABEL is to be applied. See EXPRESSION in CLASS.

```
LABEL
    EXPRESSION "Q = '' AND Diameter = '')"
    TEXT ""
END
LABEL
    EXPRESSION "Q = '' AND NOT (Diameter =='')"
    TEXT "D=[Diameter] mm"
END
LABEL
    EXPRESSION "NOT(Q = '') AND Diameter =='')"
    TEXT "Q=[Q] m³/h"
END
LABEL
    EXPRESSION "NOT(Q = '') AND NOT (Diameter =='')"
    TEXT "Q=[Q] m³/h D=[Diameter] mm"
END
```

An easier solution would be to dynamically generate the column content with an SQL query if you are using a database instead of working at Mapserver level.

Comment: Thanks. In my actual use case I have three variables, but I can make it work with less than nine cases. I am also not certain that your expressions are correct (neither that they're wrong)—I could only make it work with `('[Q]' = '')`, i.e. I had to put string variables inside square brackets and inside quotes, and wrap the entire expression in brackets instead of quotes.

Comment: Not sure exactly. Do not use so often Mapserver although use it for years so I can have made some syntax errors. At least, it gave you the clues to solve your problem